# Catching Published or UnPublished in the SetPublishStateEventArgs

Tags: event-system

Is it possible to catch if an action is Publish or UnPublish in the SetPublishStateEventArgs?

I see in [this post](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/how-to-catch-a-publish-unpublish-event-in-an-sdl-tridion-2011-event-system) I can use the PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs.

Here is the code:

```
public MyEventSystem() 
{
    EventSystem.Subscribe<RepositoryLocalObject, SetPublishStateEventArgs>(GetPublishInfo, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
}

private void GetPublishInfo(RepositoryLocalObject subject, SetPublishStateEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{

    foreach (var item in args.ProcessedItems)
    {
        string title = subject.Title;
        string publicationTarget = args.Target.Title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be missing something in your question, but isn't it as simple as looking at `args.IsPublished`?

The SetPublishState event is only called after a successful transaction, so the Page will either be published or not after it. Which would result in:

- `args.IsPublished = true` - Publish action
- `args.IsPublished = false` - UnPublish action

Comment: But a page can be published (i.e. have a state of "published") after a succesful unpublish.

Comment: @DominicCronin only for a different target, `args.IsPublished` belongs to `args.Target` here, which is not the same as the IsPublished icon on a Page in a list.